# IOS - image slideshow using PageView Controller

Tags: ios, uiimageview, slideshow

i am new to IOS Programming. i want to implement the image slideshow in my app.i am following this [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-tutorial-intro/). The tutorial is running successfully. but i want to add different images on the screen. how can i add multiple images in my screen here.the tutorial is just showing the text on the screen.first i thought why not drag a imageView on the screen, but then the image will be constant. i want to show different images

Answer (score 0):

Create your own `UIViewController` with a nib if required. Arrange the ImageViews as per your requirements and add these viewcontrollers to the Page View Controller